# ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have this query below for oracle sql:

```
SELECT
  /*+parallel(4)*/
  TO_CHAR (a.Po_Distribution_Id)           AS INTEGRATION_ID,
  MIN(c.NEED_BY_DATE)                      AS X_ORIG_NEED_BY_DT,
  b.PROMISED_DATE                          AS X_PROMISED_DT,
  MIN(c.PROMISED_DATE)                     AS X_ORIG_PROMISED_DT,
  COALESCE(b.PROMISED_DATE,b.NEED_BY_DATE) AS X_NEED_BY_DT 
      FROM PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL a
LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL b
ON a.LINE_LOCATION_ID=b.LINE_LOCATION_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ARCHIVE_ALL c
ON c.LINE_LOCATION_ID=b.LINE_LOCATION_ID
 AND a.CREATION_DATE >= '30-SEP-2017'
and rownum = 10
GROUP BY a.Po_Distribution_Id,
      b.PROMISED_DATE,
      b.PROMISED_DATE,
      b.NEED_BY_DATE
```

When i execute it, i got ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table. Need help for this error.

Comment: To get records with a.CREATION_DATE >='30-SEP-2017' use it in the WHERE clause and not in the LEFT OUTER JOIN's AND clause. You also got rownum=10, this would cause your query to return you no rows, since rownum gets incremented after the output is generated

Comment: Please give a [mre]. This error message normally arises from left joining via `(+)` not `on`. But if the former case, this is a faq, read the manual & research. [ask]

Comment: yea i agree, i wasnt able to reproduce this in Oracle 19c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below query. In the current query, your aggregation is incorrect, you have to use same function as you use in the select query. And changed the filter criteria to `WHERE` instead of `AND`. Also not sure why you are selecting `rownum=10`,it will provide you only one record. Is that fine?

```
SELECT
  /*+parallel(4)*/
  TO_CHAR (a.Po_Distribution_Id)           AS INTEGRATION_ID,
  MIN(c.NEED_BY_DATE)                      AS X_ORIG_NEED_BY_DT,
  b.PROMISED_DATE                          AS X_PROMISED_DT,
  MIN(c.PROMISED_DATE)                     AS X_ORIG_PROMISED_DT,
  COALESCE(b.PROMISED_DATE,b.NEED_BY_DATE) AS X_NEED_BY_DT 
      FROM PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL a
LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL b
ON a.LINE_LOCATION_ID=b.LINE_LOCATION_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ARCHIVE_ALL c
ON c.LINE_LOCATION_ID=b.LINE_LOCATION_ID
 WHERE a.CREATION_DATE >= '30-SEP-2017'
and rownum = 10
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (a.Po_Distribution_Id),
         b.PROMISED_DATE
         COALESCE(b.PROMISED_DATE,b.NEED_BY_DATE);
```